# Поставить фоновое изображение

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

```
var bg;
bg = game.add.graphics(0, 0);
bg.beginFill(0xCCEEFF, 1);
bg.drawRect(0, 0, game.world.width, game.world.height);
bg.endFill();
```

Как bg залить не цветом а поставить изображение?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Паучье чутьё подсказывает мне, что вы используете фреймворк [Phaser](http://phaser.io/). Если немножко почитать [документацию](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/wiki/_pages) и посмотреть [примеры](http://www.gametest.mobi/phaser/examples/), то станет ясно, что рисование изображений в Phaser выглядит как-то так:

```
game.load.image("some_image", "Graphics/some_image.png"); // подгружаем картинку

var my_image = game.add.sprite(0, 0, "some_image"); // создаём спрайт из загруженной картинки, отрисовываем его в позиции 0, 0

my_image.scale.setTo(2, 2); // масштабируем картинку; для примера я увеличил её в 2 раза, но вы должны будете расчитать увеличение исходя из соотношения размеров картинки и экрана
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!